# what are the reasons for umounting /proc filesystem?

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to write an audit program for unixs systems. First I was thinking of getting all the outputs of various native commands, such as ifconfig, df, route, and so on, depending on the system the script is executed on.

Besides being complicated to implement<sup>*</sup>, it appears to me that all the commands I need are getting informations from /proc filesystem. So that I would just directly get its structure instead of boterhing with commands compatibility.

However, I have read in various places in the web that people want to find a way to umount /proc filesystem. Why would someone need to umount this partition?

---

<sub>*: Because openbsd netstat is not the same as linux one, for instance, I need to add a switch there.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unmounting `/proc` only happens on a reboot or shutdown. It is a virtual filesystem (residing only in ram) and nothing is used on disk. Every process running on the system must be stopped in order to unmount it.

In some cases, a `chroot` is setup somewhere on the system and the currently running system `/proc` is mounted on top of it using the `-o bind` parameter. This is so the same devices and process info is available to the processes running within the `chroot`. This "copy" of the mounted filesystem can be un-mounted when all processes in the chroot have terminated. This is really the only way `/proc` can be unmounted on a live system and then, it is only a copy of the real one.

Regarding your audit program, it may be wise to stick with the binaries used on each system. Even though their output (and usage flags) may be different, they will already know how to traverse the different entries in /proc which will vary widely across versions and flavors of *nix. Good luck!